# How to implement AFNetwoking interagtion in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, cocoapods

I have Xcode 6.2 beta version. I have downloaded CocoaPods but I wasn't able to do `pod install`. I am getting an error.

Is there any shorter way to integrate **AFNetworking** in my project?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the source files in your project. Make sure to copy all [these files](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/AFNetworking).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple things to take care of when first using CocoaPods on your Mac. I myself, have encountered several obstacles.

1. Make sure you have updated version of [git](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) - with Xcode 6.2 (BETA!?) you probably have installed some ancient 1.7 version. Instal 2.0 instead.
2. Don't work in 6.2 beta, really - install 6.4 stable, it's out there.
3. Check you have the newest version of CocoaPods - as of today, it happens to 0.38.1 -> that is done, as you know by `sudo gem install cocoapods`
4. Then just simply `touch Podfile`, add whatever suits your project.

(Giving older example):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

and then run `pod install`. Don't forget to then access your project via the created workspace (`project-name.xcworkspace`) and not the original project (`project-name.xcodeproj`)!

---

**Note:**

Of course you can simply download and *copy-paste* the files in your project, but the huge benefit dependency manger such as CocoaPods or Carthage brings is that with a single line of code in the terminal you'll update all your frameworks used in your project whenever you need.